# Create ground truth in TF loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build my own model for 3D object detection. My net consist of 2 convolution network and output is of shape (128,64,8). I'm using DenseBox object detection approach and therefor my ground truth should look like this for example [ground truth for image with one object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7Mdv.png). That's first channel, there are 7 more. It's a lot of data to feed to tensorflow model so i decided to feed as label just few points(corners of bounding box) which are helpfull to get center of that circle. Then i was intended to draw that circle to some 2D array ( i also need to apply GaussianBlur to that array) and compare it in loss function.

Does someone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used `tf.py_func` to use opencv or numpy functions in tensorflow computation graph. I'm not sure but i think that this functions does not propagate gradient.